# Is there a way to increase the maximum number of tcp connections allowed to a docker container?

Tags: linux, docker

How do I configure the max allowed tcp connections to a docker container (docker on linux)?

Comment: What is the motivation to do this? if you are facing some issue regarding your container, please post some logs.

Answer (score 0):

Max TCP raw socket connections will be a 16-bit int, so 65,535 max connections (which will be part of the TCP/IP IPv4 spec, probably). Some of these are reserved for other things, so in reality around 64,000.

There's isn't a way to boost the connection limits, unless you can share sockets etc. If you've actually hit the max TCP connections, you'll need to load balance or find a way of sharing the socket connections somehow.